# Sorting repeated elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

What I try to do is to write a function sort_repeated(L) which returns a sorted list of the repeated elements in the list L.

For example,

```
>>sort_repeated([1,2,3,2,1])
[1,2]
```

However, my code does not work properly. What did I do wrong in my code?

```
def f5(nums):
    count = dict()
    if not nums:
        for num in nums:
            if count[num]:
                count[num] += 1

            else:
                count[num] = 1
        return sorted([num for num in count if count[num]>1])
    return []
```

Comment: Is your intended result `[1,2,3]` or `[1,1,2,2,3]`?

Comment: [1,2] as I wrote above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if count[num]:` will fail if the dictionary doesn't have the key already. Take a look at the various counter recipes on this site and use one instead.

Also, `not nums` is true if `nums` is an empty sequence, which means that the loop body will never be executed. Invert the condition.

Comment: Actually, that is what I intended.

'if count[num]': will fail if the dictionary doesnt have the key already, then it will go to 'count[num] = 1'

Also, if nums is empty, I intended to execute the loop body.

Comment: You misunderstand. It's not that the condition will be false, it's that **the code will crash**.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use a counter and check for values greater than 1

```
from collections import Counter

def sort_repeated(_list):
    cntr = Counter(_list)
    print sorted([x for x in cntr.keys() if cntr[x] > 1])

sort_repeated([7, 7, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 3, 4, 6, 5])
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
```